# can we do an autoincrement strings in sqlite3?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Can we  do autoincrement string in sqlite3? IF not how can we do that?
Exemple:
RY001
RY002
...
With Python, I can do it easily with print("RY"+str(rowid+1)). But how about it performances?
Thank you

Comment: Will the prefix always be `RY` and the numeric part 001 to 999 only?

Comment: it can go up to 999. Yes the prefix will always be RY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.31.0+ you can have a generated column, stored or virtual:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   str_id TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (printf('RY%03d', id)),
   <other columns>
);
```

The column `id` is declared as the primary key of the table and `AUTOINCREMENT` makes sure that no missing `id` value (because of deletions) will ever be reused.
The column `str_id` will be generated after each new row is inserted, as the concatenation of the `'RY'` and the left padded with `0`s value of `id`.
As it is, `str_id` will be `VIRTUAL`, meaning that it will be created every time you query the table.
If you add `STORED` to its definition:

```
str_id TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (printf('RY%03d', id)) STORED
```

it will be stored in the table.

Comment: Thank you but if there is always delete row. How to manage it?

Comment: @Béa If you use AUTOINCREMENT in the definition of the id then when you delete a row the deleted id will not be reused in future inserted columns. If you want the missing ids reused you can omit AUTOINCREMENT.

Comment: I agree with you...But is there any way to get the last record id and to add +1. Then add this to my pattern RY? I can do it by python but what about sqlite?
Than you

Comment: @Béa this is what the table definition in my answer does. Here: https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html you can find more about AUTOINCREMENT behavior in SQLite. For example if you delete the last inserted id, say 50 and you want the next inserted row to have 50 and not 51 then you must not use the keyword AUTOINCREMENT after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```sql
select
  printf("RY%03d", rowid) as "id"
, *
from myTable
```

?